# Inconsistent return in the code while running

Tags: python, pylint

Below is the program to convert into json.
My code is running succesfully

It will read from  the s3 bucket and convert into json

```
import csv
import logging
def read_file(bucket, key):
    try:
        read = boto3.client('s3')
        object = read.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        lines = object['Body'].read().decode('utf-8-sig').split('\n')
        csv_file = csv.DictReader(lines)
        data_list = list(csv_file)
        return data_list
    except Exception as err:
        logging.exception("Error details:-  %s", err)
```

After running in the pylint I got error

> Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. (inconsistent-return-statements)

Adding one more reference

```
try:
    for key in keys_to_match:
        if key not in dictionary.keys():
            return False
        return True
except Exception as err:
    logging.exception(" Error details:-  %s", err)
```

Comment: You don't return anything in your except clause but you do in the try clause. If you can't return a meaningful value after the error, why are you catching it?

Comment: @Simon there is no if else loop in my code

Comment: @sim doesn't matter, you have two branches but only one return, same as in the linked duplicate.

Comment: if i raise in exception wil it be solved?

Comment: @JaredSmith i have added one more reference,

Comment: @sim the new code you posted has exactly the same problem as the old code. Either return a value or reraise the error in your exception clause.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the warning tells you there are code paths where no value will be returned. If during you try block you reach an exception, you will log something and then return nothing. The linter is telling you that you should either always return or never return.

Comment: how to fix that

Comment: if i raise that, will it be solved?

Comment: Raise what ? You need to return something. For example, if your function is supposed to return a list of data objects, you could return an empty list.